# Explode array and run foreach loop

Tags: php

I have the following string stored in my database: `[gallery ids="442,443,444"]`.

I'd like to take the values from `ids` i.e. `442`, `443`, `444` and run a foreach loop.

So it would basically loop through all the integers inside `ids`.

How can I do this with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first extract the ids collectively, then make them into an array.

You could for example split the string using double quotes:

```
list (,$rawIds) = preg_split('#"#', $string);
```

and then explode the ids:

```
$ids = preg_split('#,\\s*#', $rawIds);
```

The \s* takes care of possible whitespaces (e.g. "21,22,23,   24,25").

At that point you use `$ids` as an array:

```
foreach ($ids as $index => $id) {
    print "ID #{$index} is {$id}\n";
}

ID #0 is 5
ID #1 is 8
ID #2 is 12
```

However, you'd better verify how the string got created: e.g. if it is by any chance JSON, you'd be better served by using `json_decode($string, true)`.

Comment: This is perfect. Can you explain how I then use a foreach loop on each of the IDs?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this small script:

```
<?php
// get the value from the Database
$ids = $record;  // get some procedure to get the value from the database.
// explode the value to get the list ids
$list = explode("=",$ids);
// get the list ids only
$elements = str_replace("\"","",$list[1]);
// extract all ids from the list
$array_list = explode(",",$elements);
// trigger loop to get each value
foreach($array_list  as $ value){
 echo $value."<br />"; // value for each element, i.e. 442, 443, 444,....
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$txt = '[gallery ids="442,443"]';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $txt, $match);
print_r($match); // get all matches data in an array
```